# Reload php scandir() without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using this script:

```
$userdir = '../../'.$id.'/';
    $files2 = scandir($userdir);
    $ignore = array(".", "..");


    foreach ($files2 as $value) {

        if(in_array($value, $ignore)){
        }
        else {

    echo '<img class="clickableimg" id="'.$value.'" src="../../'.$id.'/'.$value.'" />';   }
    }
```

This is from a form when the users can choose an image and upload new images.

The problem is that I want the scandir() to fire up again when the user clicks on "refresh" without loosing form data.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have to do an ajax request, and replace the div contents with the refreshed data

Comment: php runs on the server. by the time the user sees a page and can click on anything, the php script will generally have been shutdown/cleaned up/dead for a prolonged period.

Comment: use ajax. or you can show result of script in iframe and reload only iframe content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also be inclined to use AJAX (in other words passing data to external PHP scripts without reloading the page).

There are literally thousands examples on the internet as well as here on SO. When I was learning ajax, this came in very handy: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp